# c# 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current', Could not read posted values on my web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, http-post, webhooks

I am creating a single page web application which will handle the posted data from microsoft azure webhook.
I have created a Core web application and got prebuild files to run it on IIS. The issue is that i am unable to read the Posted values/Get values in my app. Here is my code in the startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace office365notification
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        public class User
        {
            public double id { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var queryVals = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(queryVals["id"]);
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have retreive the query string value like this

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
   await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Request.QueryString.Value);
});
```

And the posted field to this page/API could not retrieve with context.Response.Query or context.Response.Form. To achieve that i need to convert my project into web api type which sets up initial project with a sample controller i have implement my post method function in that sample controller. the code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;

namespace webAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Post(User user)
        {
            string userId = user.id;
            string userEmail = user.email;
            string msg = "There is no posted data!";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
            {
                WriteToLogFile("User id : " + userId + "\n" + ", User Email : " + userEmail + "\n");
                msg = "Posted data added successfully!";
            }
            return msg;
        }
    class User {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your Configure method

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Here you should have the context.
            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

Comment: i tried your solution but what i needed was exactly there. it was inside the context. i am posting the solution